# Output date for all records in SQL when date stops (must be one month gaps)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2005

I have this problem where I have data with month jumps. As you can see Record Date jumps 1 month at a time always.

I need to generate a new line for 01/01/2017. Basically I need to generate a new line each time there is one gap in month.

How could I do that? Fiscal Week is just the week in month, month is just month and year is just year. Week num is running week which started few years back and keeps accumulating, that I can look up in a special table which is not a problem, I would just use the week, year, month to get it and use min or max (first or last week of that month)

```
[Week Num] [Record Date] [Record Date] [Fiscal Year] [Fiscal Month] [Fiscal Week] [Customer #] [Group Description]
158        01/10/2016    NULL          2016          10             41            12345        aDrive
162        01/11/2016    NULL          2016          11             45            12345        aDrive
166        01/12/2016    NULL          2016          12             49            12345        aDrive
```

Basically I don't want to generate october, november, i want to generate the LAST record where there is no subsequent record but no gaps either.

Help me out.

Comment: SQL Server 2005

Comment: Huh? I can't even begin to understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: "I have this problem where I have data with month jumps."  Ok... so illustrate this in your example code.  What is provided is not clear.  You must have more data after 01/12/2016?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your question.
Try the following query maybe it'll help you. But I don't know maybe it doesn't work in SQLServer 2005 because I used recursive CTE here.

```
DECLARE @ToDate date
SET @ToDate='20171201' -- we'll calculate new rows until this date

;WITH monthCTE AS(
  -- get the last row from your table
  SELECT [Week Num],[Record Date],[Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Month],[Fiscal Week],[Customer #],[Group Description]
  FROM
    (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM [Your data]
      ORDER BY [Week Num] DESC
    ) q

  UNION ALL

  -- calculate the next row
  SELECT
    [Week Num]+DATEDIFF(WEEK,[Record Date],[New Record Date]),
    [New Record Date],
    YEAR([New Record Date]),
    MONTH([New Record Date]),
    CASE
      WHEN MONTH([New Record Date])=1 THEN 1 -- return 1 if it is the first month in the year
      ELSE [Fiscal Week]+DATEDIFF(WEEK,[Record Date],[New Record Date])
    END,
    [Customer #],
    [Group Description]
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        [Week Num],[Record Date],[Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Month],[Fiscal Week],[Customer #],[Group Description],
        DATEADD(MONTH,1,[Record Date]) [New Record Date] -- add one month to the previous date
      FROM monthCTE
      WHERE [Record Date]<@ToDate
    ) q
)
SELECT [Week Num],[Record Date],[Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Month],[Fiscal Week],[Customer #],[Group Description]
FROM [Your data]

UNION -- this operation also exclude duplicate for the last row

SELECT [Week Num],[Record Date],[Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Month],[Fiscal Week],[Customer #],[Group Description]
FROM monthCTE

ORDER BY [Week Num]
```

If I understood you rightly and it works then you'll need to check all the expressions for accuracy.